# How to make a code which finds the largest k cells and their locations, when given a table?

Tags: r

I want to know a code which finds `the largest k cells and their locations`, when given `a two dimensional table`.

for example, the given two dimensional table is as follows,

```
table_ex

   A   B   C
F 99  693  515
I 722 583  37
M 186 817  525
```

the function, which is made by a desirable code, gives the result.

```
function(table_ex, 2)

 817,  M B
 722,  I A
```

In the case described above, since k=2, the function gives two largest cells and their locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can coerce to `data.frame` then just sort using `order`:

```
getTopCells <- function(tab, n) {
  sort_df <- as.data.frame(tab)
  sort_df <- sort_df[order(-sort_df$Freq),]
  sort_df[1:n, ]
}
```

Example:

```
tab <- table(sample(c('A', 'B'), 200, replace=T),
             rep(letters[1:5], 40))
# returns:
#    a  b  c  d  e
# A 20 23 19 21 23
# B 20 17 21 19 17


getTopCells(tab, 3)

# returns:
#   Var1 Var2 Freq
# 3    A    b   23
# 9    A    e   23
# 6    B    c   21
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a reshaping approach here. The key is to save your table in a data.frame format and then save your row names as another column in that data.frame. Then you can use something like:

```
df = read.table(text="
names   A   B   C
F 99  693  515
I 722 583  37
M 186 817  525", header=T)

library(tidyr)  # to reshape your dataset
library(dplyr)  # to join commands

df %>%
  gather(names2,value,-names) %>%  # reshape your dataset
  arrange(desc(value)) %>%         # arrange your value column
  slice(1:2)                       # pick top 2 rows

#   names names2 value
# 1     M      B   817
# 2     I      A   722
```

PS: In case you don't want to use any packages, or don't want to use data.frames but your original table, I'm sure you'll find some great alternative replies here.

Comment: But here `df` is a data.frame, not a table

Comment: Yes @arvi1000 . Probably I wasn't very clear that he has to make the table a data.frame and then add the row names as another column. I'll update my initial description, otherwise it's misleading.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using only 'base' and without coercing into a data.frame :

First let's create a table:

```
set.seed(123)
tab <- table(sample(c('A', 'B'), 200, replace=T),
             rep(letters[1:5], 40))
     a  b  c  d  e
  A 15 13 18 20 22
  B 25 27 22 20 18
```

and now:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(tab)){
  cat(dimnames(tab)[[1]][i], which.max(tab[i,]),max(tab[i,]),'\n')
}

A 5 22 
B 2 27
```